# How Gr(2,7) and Gr(3,6) are related?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Consider the two types of Grassmannians Gr(2,7) and Gr(3,6) having  their plucker embeddings in $\mathbb P^{20}$ and $\mathbb P^{19}$ respectivley. The first one is 10-dimensional and latter is 9-dimensional, so each having codimension 10. We can easily compute their defining equations and both of them are defined by  35 equations.

By using computer algebra system(such as Macaulay 2 or Magma) we can also compute their Hilbert series and so the Hilbert numerator. If we do the computation then both  varieties have basically same numerator, which suggests that both idels have the same(kind of) free resolution.

This raises the question whether  Gr(3,6) is a linear section of Gr(2,7) or not.?

Comment: Can you give more details on these Hilbert series?

Comment: @Sasha.. Sorry, I Didn't get what exactly may I let you know about them? 
    


Comment: I know what I want the answer to be. Let $\Delta$ be the Schubert divisor in $G(2,7)$ -- this is the set of $2$-planes in $7$-space which meet a fixed $5$-plane nontransversely. This is a hyperplane section of $G(2,7)$. I want there to be a flat degeneration from $G(3,6)$ to $\Delta$. No idea about how to find it though...

Comment: @M I - I mean, what is the precise relation between the numerators and denominators of Hilbert series?

Comment: @Sasha..In fact the Hilbert numerator is
$1-35t^2+140t^3-189t^4-112t^5+735t^6-1080t^7+735t^8-112t^9-189t^{10}+140t^{11}-35t^{12}+t^{14},$ for both varieites. The denomenator is obviously $(1-t)^{21}$ and $(1-t)^{20}$.

Comment: @Sasha....did you find it of any use at all?

Comment: @M I - Now I understand that the numerators are identical and the denominators differ by the factor $(1-t)$. 

Comment: In each case, you could compute their _multigraded_ Hilbert series; these are of course different because they involve a different number of variables. But then it would be worth knowing if the second one is a specialization of the first, or how drastically you have to specialize each of their variables before the series agree. The point being that it would constrain what sort of degeneration (for David and David) to look for, i.e. how equivariant one might hope the degeneration to be.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know whether the ideals have the same kind of free resolutions, but $Gr(3,6)$ is definitely not a hyperplane section of $Gr(2,7)$. Otherwise, their $H^{\leq 8}$ would be the same by the Lefschetz hyperplane theorem. However, $H^6(Gr(3,6))$ is 3-dimensional and is spanned by $c_1^3, c_1c_2$ and $c_3$, and $H^6(Gr(2,7))$ is 2-dimensional: it is spanned by $c_1^3$ and $c_1c_2$. Here $c_i$'s are the Chern classes of the respective tautological bundles.

Comment: Can you please give me a reference for this computation?

Comment: M I -- the cohomology of the Grassmannians is described in many places. in particular, the rank of $H^i(Gr(j,k))$ is the number of partitions of $i$ into $\leq j$ positive integers $\leq k-j$ (see e.g. Milnor-Stasheff, Characteristic classes, corollary 6.7 for the real case; the complex case is similar. Another method: use the fact that the cohomology is generated as an algebra by the Chern classes of the universal bundle, with one relation: the total Chern class of the universal bundle times the total Chern class of the universal quotient bundle is 1 (c.f. Milnor-Stasheff, problem 7B).

Answer (score 9):

There is a theorem of Fujita saying that Grassmannian is never a hyperplane section of a smooth variety unless it is $P^n$ or $Gr(2,4)$.

Comment: I think the theorem is about the Grassmannian corresponding to the special or general linear group. This is not true if you take the isotropic Lagrangiann Grassmannians LGr(2,6), which is a linear section of Gr(2,6). 

Comment: This theorem is about usual Grassmannians --- $Gr(k,n)$ is a hyperplane section of a smooth variety if and only if $k = 1$, or $k = n-1$, or $(k,n) = (2,4)$.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: The following idea doesn't work, for kind of obvious reasons (see the comments).

---

As other answers have pointed out, the answer to the original question is no.  However, taking up the idea from David Speyer's comment, both $Gr(3,6)$ and the Schubert divisor $\Delta$ in $Gr(2,7)$ are linear sections of $Gr(3,8)$, *by linear subspaces of the same dimension*.  Specifically, as Schubert varieties inside $Gr(3,8)$, $$Gr(3,6) = \Omega_{(2,2,2)}$$ and $$\Delta = \Omega_{(5,1)}.$$  (I'm using notation where $\Omega_\lambda$ has codimension $|\lambda|$, for $\lambda$ a partition inside the $3 \times (8-3)$ rectangle.)  One checks that these two Schubert varieties are both defined by the vanishing of 36 Plücker coordinates (on $Gr(3,8)$).

Taking any curve in the Grassmannian of codimension-36 subspaces inside ${\Bbb P}^N$, where $N = \binom{8}{3}-1$, connecting the two linear spaces cutting out $Gr(3,6)$ and $\Delta$, you should get a flat family having these two as fibers, explaining why they have the same Hilbert polynomial.

Comment: This is a nice idea, but it doesn't work. First I'll explain what's wrong with the argument, then how to know it can't work. $G(3,8)$ only has dimension $15$, so a generic linear space of codimension $36$ misses $G(3,6)$ entirely. It is not clear that you can move from one of the codim $36$ spaces to the other without passing through some intermediate spaces that miss $G(3,8)$, in which case your family isn't flat. And, in fact, you can't. $G(3,6)$ and $G(2,7)$ have different cohomology classes in $G(3,8)$ so they can't be linked by a flat family within $G(3,8)$.

Comment: Whoops!  Thanks for the correction... after posting, I got a feeling something was off...

Comment: @Dave & David..Is there any other possible reason for them to have same Hilbert Series?

Comment: @ M I, in some sense, no, this is the only possible reason.  If two subvarieties of ${\Bbb P}^n$ have the same Hilbert polynomial, then they are related by a flat family (by connectivity of the Hilbert scheme).

Comment: @Dave & M I, the connectivity of the Hilbert scheme means that there is a flat family over a connected, put possibly reducible base connecting the two varieties. To connect them by a single curve, and for that curve to be rational is a stronger statement and is not true for arbitrary pairs of varieties with the same Hilbert series.

Comment: Dustin, I agree -- there's no reason to expect the flat family to be over ${\Bbb P}^1$.  Nonetheless, there must be some family.  (And given that we're talking about Grassmannians, one could *hope* for a nice family!)  David's comment about non-equal cohomology classes in $Gr(3,8)$ still prohibits it from being a flat family (by any chain of curves) inside that Grassmannian, though.

Comment: Note that two subvarieties of $X$ (projective) may have the same Hilbert series, but not be connectable within $X$. Dumbest case: $X$ is two points. Less dumb: $X = P^1 \times P^1$. (The better thing to hold constant is the class in $K$-homology of $X$.)